# How can I get scroll distance in a listview (listview item height not equal)?

Tags: android, listview

I want my listview to get a scroll distance with my listview height not being equal. I have tried `getScrollY`, with this I can only get the item's height same as ScrollY.

```
public int getScrollY() {
    View c = mListView.getChildAt(0);
    if (c == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int firstVisiblePosition = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int top = c.getTop();
    return -top + firstVisiblePosition * c.getHeight() ;
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried/researched anything?

Comment: yes I edited it above. Please remove the minus :)

Comment: Minus wasn't me :)